# Set default database to user SQL Server (Azure)

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to create a database user from C# in Azure SQL Server. But I need to set its default database (`DEFAULT_DATABASE`) but the script doesn't work on Azure.

Does anyone know how can I do it?

```
CREATE USER newlogin FOR LOGIN newlogin;
ALTER LOGIN newlogin WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = myDatabase;
```

but it throws an error:

> Keyword or statement option 'default_database' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

After I created the user and try to connect to SQL Server, this error occurs:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in Azure but, as @Larnu alludes to, it isn't exactly straightforward. The advice given in their answer **will** work for a single login but is probably not something that is practical or desirable in any production scenario. I would suggest doing the following:

1. have a group created in Active Directory that encapsulates the users that you want this behavior to apply to; assign the appropriate members to this group
2. add the group as a new login to the target Azure Sql Server; alter the login to have the appropriate database set as default
3. add the group as a new user to the default database that was assigned previously

The code for this is slightly different in Azure Sql Server than on-prem:

```
-- run in [master]
create login [YourGroupName] from external provider;
alter login [YourGroupName] with default_database = [YourDefaultDatabase];

-- run in [YourDefaultDatabase]
create user [YourGroupName] from login [YourGroupName];
```

**Edit:**

Users in Azure Sql Server are typically contained within a single database and don't even exist at the "server level"; more info can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/contained-database-users-making-your-database-portable). If you simply want to create a user in an Azure Sql Server database then all you need to do is write a statement in the form of `create user [YourUserName] with password = 'YourSecret';`. Note that this *assumes you're already connected to the database that you intend to create the user in.* If you're in a context such as `[master]`, and have no ability to change the connection string, then you'll need to use [ChangeDatabase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.changedatabase) first.

Answer (score 3):

I found something, that can be useful. 
if I want to connect to SQL server with management studio, I have to use "connection properties" and set the default database.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*select the **master** database, if not already selected and create the login*

```
CREATE LOGIN [myAccountName] WITH PASSWORD = 'myPassword' 
GO
```

*this step is to grant a connection access to master database and be able to login in SSMS 
without changing the default database in the connection page*

```
CREATE USER [myAccountName] FOR LOGIN [myAccountName] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [dbo]
```

*switch onto **your user database** and create the user for the login*

```
CREATE USER [myAccountName] FOR LOGIN [myAccountName] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [dbo]
```

*grant the needed permissions to your user*

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'myAccountName'
```

Answer (score -1):

The default database is always the `[master]` db. Use connection string database/initial catalog parameter as default database instead. To add specific user, login to db server master using the owner account.

Then, in `[master]` db you can create new user login by, e.g.:

```
CREATE LOGIN dev_team WITH PASSWORD = 'P@ssW0rd'
GO
```

Then switch to the desired database for `dev_team` login. Create the user and grant access to the user in that database, e.g.:

```
USE [myseconddb]
GO
CREATE USER dev_team FOR LOGIN dev_team
GO
GRANT EXECUTE TO dev_team
GRANT INSERT TO dev_team
GRANT DELETE TO dev_team
GRANT UPDATE TO dev_team
GRANT SELECT TO dev_team
GO
```

Or just switch to the desired database,

```
USE [myseconddb]
GO
CREATE USER dev_team2 WITH PASSWORD = 'P@ssW0rd'
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'dev_team2'
GO
GRANT EXECUTE TO dev_team2
GRANT INSERT TO dev_team2
GRANT DELETE TO dev_team2
GRANT UPDATE TO dev_team2
GRANT SELECT TO dev_team2
GO
```

The `dev_team` and `dev_team2` user then cannot access other database except `[myseconddb]`.
You can then use in the connection string, e.g. **userid** `dev_team2` and **password** `P@ssW0rd` and **initial catalog** name `myseconddb` (as default).

I hope that helps.

Comment: thank you, but is not working yet, because the problem is if you want to connect to SQL server with management studio.

Comment: Well, that's not your main question. SSMS contruct the connection string when we enter the login credential. Is just a connection string. And you can specify the initial catalog with the database name.